# I closed the terminal while upgrading ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.10

I was Using ubuntu 20.04 and I wanted to upgrade it to 20.10.
While upgrading I closed the terminal beacause it stoped to work and I can't open apps like Settings ubuntu software and the terminal, I even can't restart.I tried to use the terminal in Vs Code but I get always this error message
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 73120 (groovy)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: Reboot your computer and it should be solved

Comment: It doesn't allow me to restart

Comment: What happens when you enter the command `reboot`

Comment: It says Oh something has gone wrong! Contact a system administrator

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to deal with that. Hopefully someone else would be able to address the issue

Comment: Run `sudo reboot`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See terminal text. 'Waiting for cache lock' error. How to fix? I'm on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352416/see-terminal-text-waiting-for-cache-lock-error-how-to-fix-im-on-ubuntu-21)